# JavaScript If / else statement not return false statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, if-statement

Function returns true, however if / else statement is logging false result. Any  idea where I'm going wrong?

```js
function loginDetails(arrayCheck, value) {
 for(i = 0; i < arrayCheck.length; i++){
   if(arrayCheck[i] === value){
    return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
  }

 var username = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
  
  document.write('Login Details: ', loginDetails(username, 9), '</p>');
 
  if(loginDetails === true) {
  document.write('Redirect ....Welcome !!</p>'); 
  
  } else {
  document.write('There seems to be an error please try again !!');
  }
```

Comment: `loginDetails` is a function. It will never be equal to `true`.

Comment: You probably want to do is save the return of your function `loginDetails` to a variable and then compare in the condition.

Comment: `if(loginDetails(username, 9) === true){...} `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`loginDetails` is a function. You then test to see if it is boolean `true`. Funnily enough, it never will be!

I presume you actually want to run the function. You will need to cache the result in order not to run it twice:

```js
function loginDetails(arrayCheck, value) {
 for(i = 0; i < arrayCheck.length; i++){
       if(arrayCheck[i] === value){
        return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

var username = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

var loggedIn = loginDetails(username, 9);
  
document.write('Login Details: ', loggedIn, '</p>');
 
if(loggedIn === true) {
    document.write('Redirect ....Welcome !!</p>'); 
} else {
    document.write('There seems to be an error please try again !!');
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for pointing that, much appreciated...very much of a newbie on JS.

Comment: @Evans If you're learning from a resource that uses `document.write`, use something different. `document.write` has almost no use in modern Javascript; it's a relic of the 90s!

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I am two weeks into my JavaScript journey, any advise or tips would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by `if(loginDetails === true)` ? This doesn't pass any parameters to `loginDetails` function.
Instead try `if(loginDetails(username, 9) === true)`. Hope this works.
 Else store `loginDetails(username, 9)` in a variable and check whether that variable is `true`?

Answer (score 0):

`loginDetails` is a function I suppose  you want to check its result to be equal with true.

```js
function loginDetails(arrayCheck, value) {
 for(i = 0; i < arrayCheck.length; i++){
   if(arrayCheck[i] === value){
    return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
  }

 var username = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

    var loginDetailsResult = loginDetails(username, 9);
  
  document.write('Login Details: ',loginDetailsResult, '</p>');
 
  if(loginDetailsResult === true) {
  document.write('Redirect ....Welcome !!</p>'); 
  
  } else {
  document.write('There seems to be an error please try again !!');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if the ***reference*** to the function is equal to true, which will always evaluate to false. A function and a boolean are different types and therefore comparing for strict equality will always return false. I have corrected the code, so that the function is called, and the result of the function is compared, instead of the reference to the function.

```js
function loginDetails(arrayCheck, value) {
 for(i = 0; i < arrayCheck.length; i++){
   if(arrayCheck[i] === value){
    return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
  }

 var username = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
  
  document.write('Login Details: ', loginDetails(username, 9), '</p>');
 
  if(loginDetails(username, 9) === true) {
  document.write('Redirect ....Welcome !!</p>'); 
  
  } else {
  document.write('There seems to be an error please try again !!');
  }
```